# How to properly use spray.io LruCache

Tags: scala, caching, spray

I am quite an unexperienced spray/scala developer, I am trying to properly use spray.io LruCache. I am trying to achieve something very simple. I have a kafka consumer, when it reads something from its topic I want it to put the value it reads to cache. 
Then in one of the routings I want to read this value, the value is of type string, what I have at the moment looks as follows:

```
object MyCache {

  val cache: Cache[String] = LruCache(
    maxCapacity      = 10000,
    initialCapacity  = 100,
    timeToLive       = Duration.Inf,
    timeToIdle       = Duration(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
   )
}
```

to put something into cache i use following code:

```
def message() = Future { new String(singleMessage.message()) }
MyCache.cache(key, message)
```

Then in one of the routings I am trying to get something from the cache:

```
val res = MyCache.cache.get(keyHash)
```

The problem is the type of res is Option[Future[String]], it is quite hard and ugly to access the real value in this case. Could someone please tell me how I can simplify my code to make it better and more readable ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to get the value out of the Future.  Instead call `map` on the Future to arrange for work to be done on the value when the Future is completed, and then complete the request with that result (which is itself a Future).  It should look something like this:

```
path("foo") {
  complete(MyCache.cache.get(keyHash) map (optMsg => ...))
}
```

Also, if `singleMessage.message` does not do I/O or otherwise block, then rather than creating the Future like you are

```
Future { new String(singleMessage.message) }
```

it would be more efficient to do it like so:

```
Future.successful(new String(singleMessage.message))
```

The latter just creates an already completed Future, bypassing the use of an ExecutionContext to evaluate the function.

If `singleMessage.message` *does* do I/O, then ideally you would do that I/O with some library (like Spray client, if it's an HTTP request) that returns a Future (rather than using `Future { ... }` to create another thread which will block).

Comment: I like the trick with Future.successful(new String(singleMessage.message)), thanks, the message method doesnt do any I/O so this solution is perfect for me.